# Trouble with PHP array_diff

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

We upload a lot of photos to WordPress. We do not use them all though. The unused ones remain "attached" to the post it's not in which makes it hard to go back and delete it.

I've build 2 arrays. One array contains all of the images from the post content (`$postImages`). The other array contains all of the images WordPress database have attached to the post (`$mediaImages`).

I'm trying to identify which images appear in the database, but not in the post. This way I can detach the image from within the database.

I'm using `array_diff` to compare the two arrays, however it's not showing the odd man out. It appears to be showing the matches.

Here's my arrays:

Call this one `$postImages`:

`var_dump($postImages);`

```
array(3) {
  [2]=>
  string(64) "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/photoblog1.jpg"
  [0]=>
  string(64) "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/photoblog2.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(64) "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/photoblog3.jpg"
}
```

And `$mediaImages`:

`var_dump($mediaImages);`

```
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(64) "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/photoblog1.jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(64) "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/photoblog2.jpg"
  }
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(64) "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/photoblog3.jpg"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(62) "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/IMG_0069.jpg"
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$matches = array_diff($postImages, $mediaImages);
print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [2] => http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/photoblog1.jpg
    [0] => http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/photoblog2.jpg
    [1] => http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/photoblog3.jpg
)
```

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/IMG_0069.jpg
)
```

Comment: `$mediaImages` is an array of arrays of strings, while `$postimages` is simply an array of strings. You can't diff arrays that have  inherrently different structures and expect to get valid results.

Comment: Good catch. I missed that, must have been staring too long. Is there a way to condense `$mediaImages` into the same format as `$postImages`?

Comment: array_map/foreach over mediaimages and build the same structure as in $postimages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marc B pointed out in the comments, `$mediaImages` is an array of arrays of strings, while `$postimages` is just an array of strings.

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) with a custom callback to create the `$mediaImages` array:

```
$mediaImages = array_map(function($item) { 
    return $item[0]; 
}, $mediaImages);
```

Also, note that you have the parameters for [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) backwards. The correct order is:

```
array_diff($arrayToCompareFrom , $arrayToCompareAgainst);
```

So to compare `$postImages` against `$mediaImages`, you'd need:

```
$matches = array_diff($mediaImages, $postImages);
print_r($matches);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/84011)

Comment: The demo helped me visualize it. Worked great.

Comment: @Pat: Glad to have been of help! :)